# Program Practice Exercise On Streams C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, stream

so I'm practing using stream for the future when I want to make a video game with just text but I 'm having a problem.This ebook I'm using wants me to Write a program that reads a text file containing floating-point numbers. Print the average of the numbers in the file. Prompt the user for the file name.

Here is my work so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream Practice_Text;

    double Numbers[5] = { 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.3, 2.1 };

    Practice_Text.open("./Point_Numbers");

    Practice_Text << Numbers;

    Practice_Text.close();

    double practice_mode[5];

    double avg_number;

    double First_Num;

    ifstream Open_Text;

    Open_Text.open("./Point_Numbers");

    Open_Text >> First_Num[1];

    cout << First_Num[1];

    Open_Text.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Now please forgive the use of using namespace as I know that it's not recommended but I wanted to focus on using streams here. I used an array of five elements and named it Numbers. I then put it inside the file, close it, and then reopened it in the hopes of printing out the average of each number.

Now I know that what I'm doing is not the way to print out all the numbers then printing out the average, but what I was trying to do was to get out the first number and print it, to at least know that I'm on the right track but I keep getting zero instead, what am I doing wrong here? I understand that I can do it with pointers but I would rather do it with what I have here.

Comment: What's `First_Num[1]` supposed to be?

Comment: "`Practice_Text<<Numbers`" -- this doesn't do what you think it does. Did you actually check to see what was written to the file? Furthermore, no self-respecting C++ compiler will compile your "`Open_Text>>First_Num[1];`" without complaining and producing a fatal error message. Please show your real program.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your compiler errors:

- You can't directly write an array to a file. The array decays to the pointer to the first element
- You can open a file with the fstream constructor
- The fstream destructor can also close your file.
- `First_Num` is a double, not an array. You can't subscript it
- I removed unused variables
- I added checks if the file was correctly opened
- I removed `using namespace std;`. It's dangerous, especially for beginners. Many beginner don't know with names are already used in that namespace. They use the same names for their variables or functions and get a program with strange behavior.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

int main()
{
    double Numbers[5] = { 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.3, 2.1 };

    {
        ofstream Practice_Text("./Point_Numbers");
        if (!Practice_Text) return EXIT_FAILURE;
        for (const auto &Number: Number) {
            Practice_Text << Number;
        }
    }

    double First_Num;

    {
        ifstream Open_Text("./Point_Numbers");
        if (!Open_Text) return EXIT_FAILURE;
        Open_Text >> First_Num;
    }

    cout << First_Num;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out but think you can go into detail step by step on what you did please? Could you explain:  if (!Practice_Text) return EXIT_FAILURE;
        for (const auto &Number: Number)  ?

Comment: `if (!Practice_Text) return EXIT_FAILURE;` checks if the file was correctly opened and ends the program with an error code if it failed. `for (const auto &Number: Number)` is a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)